# How to register custom user control from outside my project in ascx

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I'm developing a custom asp.net user control (.net Framework 4.0) within a large solution that consists of many different projects. As part of the implementation, I've got to include in my UC another UC from another project (within the same solution). Let's say my UC is located in project A: I need to include in it another UC from project B.
Although project A already references project B, looks like it is not possible to register the UC from B within my UC in A:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ucA.ascx.cs" Inherits="A.ucA" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/<path to B>/ucB.ascx" TagName="ucb" TagPrefix="b" %>
```

If I proceed in this way, all instances of `<b:ucb>` are generated in code behind as `System.Web.UI.UserControl` instead of the correct type (`ucB`). If I move `ucB.ascx` inside project A and adjust the path in the Register declaration, code generation correctly generates instances of `ucB`.
Is there a simple, non-invasive way to achieve this result? Since my UC is part of a large solution, **it's important for me to preserve the location of files and to avoid modifications to the web.config** as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the best way to solve this problem, in my case, is just to declare the included UC as a protected property of the container UC, so as to inhibit code generation just for that particular item:

```
public partial class ucA : UserControl
{
    protected ucB b;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In previous versions of ASP.NET developers imported and used both custom server controls and user controls on a page by adding <%@ Register %> directives to the top of pages like so:

```
 <%@ Register TagPrefix="scott" TagName="header" Src="Controls/Header.ascx" %><%@ egister TagPrefix="scott" TagName="footer" Src="Controls/Footer.ascx" %><%@ Register TagPrefix="ControlVendor" Assembly="ControlVendor" %><html><body>  <form id="form1"  runat="server"> <scott:header ID="MyHeader" runat="server" />   </form> </body> </html>
```

in web.config

```
<controls>
    <add tagPrefix="scottgu" src="~/Controls/Header.ascx" tagName="header"/>
    <add tagPrefix="scottgu" src="~/Controls/Footer.ascx" tagName="footer"/>
    <add tagPrefix="ControlVendor" assembly="ControlVendorAssembly"/>
  </controls>
```

Read more here

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-how-to-register-user-controls-and-custom-controls-in-web-config

Comment: Unfortunately, that was exactly what I was trying to avoid: I'm modifying an old, huge solution that is already installed in many production environments, and my intention was to limit my editing to just the UC I'm working on. If I have to modify shared files, I think it's better for me to switch back to no code generation at all (as it was before I started my work). Thanks for your answer, anyway.